# Get more than 6 tag suggestions

Tags: feature-request, support, tags

Sometimes I have trouble finding tags I know must exist but I'm unsure of their wording. I try my best to guess the wording but I don't always succeed.

Is there already a feature for getting more than 6 tag suggestions?

If not, should there be?

These are what I mean by tag suggestions:

[image: tag suggestions]

The real life case that came up just before this was on Stack Overflow where I was looking for "stack" in the assembly sense. Nothing appropriate came up in the 6 suggestions and it turned out I should have tried "stackframe" but it took a while to figure that out.

Comment: As for the current behavior, max is 6 tags indeed. I've deleted my answer as got your question wrong (you've already noticed that :).

Comment: You can go to the Tags page and search for related tags, if you can't find what you need.

Comment: @Won't: But that’s nothing you can expect of inexperienced users. Thus, this limitation is likely to lead to mistagged questions.

Comment: 99% of mistagged questions I've ever seen are questions tagged with stuff the user's application uses but has nothing to do with the question itself. Like "Entity framework context throws transaction aborted exception" tagged WPF, MVVM.